# Magento 2.2.x Grids Customers,Products,Orders Empty

Tags: magento, magento2

Install Magento2.2.0
PHP 7.01

For some reason Order, Customer, Products Grid are not working they do have a waiting circle move but after a second I see no display and its just white page.

I've over 20K Orders, 40K Customers and only 1K Products.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admin grid data is stored separately and built via indexing. If this is a new build (with migrated data) you'll need to reindex:

```
./bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: Problem was not that problem was due to Google page speed module once I disable that in my nginx everything seems to be working just fine